# How do I filter the Logs by HTTP status code in the GAE Admin Dashboard

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, search, logging

In the Google AppEngine Dashboard, there's a page where I can view all my application logs.

I want to filter logs by their HTTP status code, like 200, 404, or 503, for example.

How do I do this? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter by labels, set the status to the desired one.

For example:

```
status:500
```

Screenshot:

[image: App Engine log filtering]